# Resizing and cropping images to an aspect ratio of 6x4 with width of 1024 pixels

Tags: command-line, image-manipulation, imagemagick

I have a mixed set of images, each one has a slightly different resolution with a slightly different aspect ratio from other images.

I have tried using commands like

```
convert -resize
```

and

```
convert -crop
```

but can't seem to figure out the correct command to make all images have a width of 1024 and an aspect ratio of 6x4, without causing the image to stretch or get squashed.

Comment: In the future, please [don't crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073) ([SU version](http://superuser.com/questions/275127/resizing-and-cropping-images-to-6x4-to-width-of-1024)). If you want a post moved to another site, you can flag it and ask a mod on that site to move it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want all your photos to be 6x4 with a width of 1024, right? That means they should be 683 pixels high.

If that is correct, what you're looking for is ...

```
convert  <input_image>  -resize 1024x683^  -gravity center  -extent 1024x683  <output_image>
```

... where you would replace *<input_image>* with the filename of the image you want to resize, and *<output_image>* with the new filename.

This will crop the edges to fit the aspect and resize them to 1024x683. It will make small images larger, as well as making large images smaller to fit your size.

When you want to resize all images in a directory, you'll need to write a quick bash script, which would look like ...

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./*.[jJ][pP][gG]
do
    echo "$f"
    convert "$f" -resize 1024x683^ -gravity center -extent 1024x683 "print_$f"
done
```

You then just make the script executable. (Say you saved the script as *rename.sh*, you run `chmod u+x rename.sh`.) Then you run the script `./rename.sh` which will resize all the images in the same directory.

Comment: 1024:768 is 4:3

Comment: He want's his images to be in 6:4

Comment: Yes, they should be 6:4 for printing purposes.  As the printer I will be using gives best results if the images are 6:4.  Any other aspect ratio, it the prints will end up showing blank white borders top/bottom, or left/right.

Comment: @Musaul, if I use that command and replace <input_image> and <output_image> with *,  will that resize and crop all images in the given directory?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a little script to rename all images in the same directory. On a sidenote though, 1024x683 is a very low resolution for printing photos.

Comment: What resolution would you recommend the 6x4 images be?  They will be printed on 6" by 4" photo paper.

Comment: According to  http://www.photokaboom.com/photography/learn/printing/resolution/1_which_resolution_print_size_viewing_distance.htm you'd want them to be at least 1878 pixels wide. So, if your question's answered, do you mind accepting the answer. Cheers :)

Comment: In your bash script, it has *.jpg.  Some of these images are *.JPG, will the case difference stop some of the images from resizing?

Comment: updated it again to match both character cases.